# How to isolate css in dynamically loaded component

Tags: html, css, jsf

I have a less library that has multiple versions.
I have the main page that uses V1 of this library.
At a point a component of the page uses V2 of this library.
My problem is that when that component is loaded that uses V2 the styles are applied on the whole page.
Unfortunately the library is not backward compatible so it ruins the whole page :|.

Is it possible to isolate somehow that inner component from the rest of the page?

CSS Page:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: You can always use the old and dirty iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put a unique identifier (id or class) on the Inner Page container, and cascade from that container in your V2 CSS to affect only its contents.

```
#inner-page input { width: 100%; }
#inner-page p { margin-bottom: 20px; }

Or LESS eg:

#inner-page { 
    input {
        width: 100%;
    }
    p { 
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
}
```

This will affect content in a container with a unique id whether it is dynamic or not.